# Можно ли закрасить фон за текстом в консольном приложении windows?

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте!
Если можно, то как сделать такую штуку в 
консольном приложении windows:
[image]

Насчет цветных прямоугольников, очень желательно создавать их в любой последовательности.

Спасибо.

Comment: Конечно можно: http://google.com/search?q=site:hashcode.ru+SetConsoleTextAttribute